# How to compile MobileFirst 'apps' for specific envirronment?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying compile mobile applications using 'ant' task as shown below

```
  <target name="target-name">
    <app-builder
        worklightserverhost="localhost:9080"
        applicationFolder="/home/apps/CLSDashboard"
        environments="desktopbrowser,ipad"
        nativeProjectPrefix=""
        outputFolder="bin/" />
  </target>
```

But it errors as shown below

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/clsapp/build_apps_and_adapters.xml:14: Failed building application: You are trying to build iOS environment, but the required attribute 'nativeProjectPrefix' is missing. Add 'nativeProjectPrefix' attribute with project name as value to <app-builder> task and re-run the script.
```

Though I can understand the error how to avoid building apps for other environments (or)  otherwise I want to compile 'apps' only for 'desktop' and 'iPad'

Answer (score 0):

Since you're attempting to build an iOS environment (iPad...) you also need to specify a value for the `nativeProjectPrefix` property. The value should be the name of the project.

[Per the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_apps.html):

> The nativeProjectPrefix attribute is mandatory when you build iOS
>   applications

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I did not notice that and now compilation is successful